# Show values on each column in Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js

I am working with Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs) and I am dealing with some problems here.

1. Is it possible to show values for each data point? It seems it is lacking that functionality or am I wrong?
   I am also using the stacked bar chart (with additional line chart applied on it) so I would like to show the value for each data point for these two bar data sets (excluding the Line chart)
2. The app is made with Ionic 2 (Angular2) and it seems, that I don't have all of the possibilites to call different helpers provided by Chart class. I see that a lot of examples include such things.
3. Is it safe to use this in production, regarding the support of the project?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You can do point #1 with d3.js. The d.ts file exist in Definetly Typed.

Comment: 1. That means for the whole chart right? Or is there just a small tweak with D3.js?

What does d.ts help to me? Should I update it perhaps?

Comment: Both solutions should work. It's more clean to recreate the whole chart I think. The d.ts is just the deffinitions you need (in this case for d3) when you code in typescript. Here is the d.ts: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/d3
Here is the d3 lib: https://d3js.org/

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly, I need to create the chart with D3.js instead with chart.js right?

Comment: And how can I "add" only the values to already created <canvas> graph?

Comment: d3 helps you manipulate the dom driven by you data. You can do whatever you want with that. I can't give you a course of d3 here. But you give your dataset to d3 then for each element in your dataset, you specify rules for position(x,y), height, width, color and whatever you want base on the data value and on the index of the element.